# Unable to assert constraints related to the screen bounds

Tags: swift, constraints

Im trying to do unit testing on my UI elements in a Swift application.

Here is the code I have defining the constraints :

```
container.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.topAnchor, constant:7).isActive = true
container.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leftAnchor, constant:34).isActive = true
container.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.rightAnchor, constant:-34).isActive = true
container.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.bottomAnchor, constant:-7).isActive = true
container.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: UIScreen.main.bounds.height * 0.062).isActive = true
```

And here my attempt to assert the geometry of the view :

```
XCTAssertTrue(subject.container.frame.origin.y - 7 == subject.contentView.frame.origin.y)
XCTAssertTrue(subject.container.frame.origin.x - 34  == subject.contentView.frame.origin.x)
XCTAssertTrue(subject.container.frame.origin.x + subject.container.frame.size.width + 34 == subject.contentView.frame.origin
            .x + subject.contentView.frame.size.width)
XCTAssertTrue(subject.container.frame.origin.y + subject.container.frame.size.height + 7 == subject.contentView.frame.origin
        .y + subject.contentView.frame.size.height)
XCTAssertTrue(subject.container.frame.size.height == floor(UIScreen.main.bounds.height * 0.062) )
```

All of them work fine except for the last one. The last one fails and If I print the corresponding values I get :

```
print("---->",subject.container.frame.size.height)
print("---->",floor((UIScreen.main.bounds.height) * 0.062))
```

Result :

```
----> 30.0
----> 55.0
```

I dont get why the values are different. This is a constant issue with all my views. I can assert all the constraints but as soon as I get the screen bounds into play then the values differ between the constraint and the assertion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already have a left, right, top and bottom anchor constraint. The exact size and position of the view can be computed from these 4 constraints.

Adding a height constraint makes the system over-constrained causing the layout engine to relax one of the constraints.

That's why the height constraint test is failing because the height is not actually equal to what you are giving in the constraint.

Comment: You are right. I missed to see that!! Thanks so much!